# get product of a special word with characters

Tags: python, python-itertools

i have a some characters for example : `a,b,c` and i also have  special word / words for ex: `fish`
my problem is :

> How find all product of a,b,c , fish  with itertools ?

i want this out puts : `aaafish`,`aabfish`,`aacfish`,...,`afishba`,`afishbb`,...,`fishccc`
 in the other word i want the word (**fish**) *repeat* in all product of **a,b,c**

here is my code :

```
alpha ='abc'
special='fish'

  for i in itertools.product(alpha , repeat = 3):
   print (''.join(i+tuple(special)))
```

in this code (fish) always get end of result

> Note 1: a,b,c are small examples i maybe have a,b,c,d,e,... and other chars

Comment: This is exactly what you asked the code to do. Try analysing how exactly `itertools.product` works. You can improve this code adding additional for loop inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You want to use `itertools` to produce all the combinations of 'a', 'b', and 'c'. Then, for each combination, insert the word 'fish' and each position in the word.

```
import itertools

alpha = 'abc'
special = 'fish'

for characters in itertools.product(alpha, repeat=3):
    for idx in range(4):
        word = "".join(characters[:idx]) + special + "".join(characters[idx:])
        print(word)
```